# In Android, Which is the best way to test Internet is working before making HTTP calls?

Tags: android, http, testing, asynchronous

I am using ***isConnected()*** method to test Internet is working or not, However, When Mobile data is on but net is not working (happens when travelling) or Wifi is on but not connected to internet, the method returns true and my app crashes.

I did some finding and found that I need to ping Google also 
so I tried using ***internetConnectionAvailable(1000)***. Even if Internet is working fine, this method sometimes return false. Can anybody help me with a better solution?

```
 //Check device has Internet connection
    public boolean isConnected()    {
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) c.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected())
            return true;
        else    {
            //Custom Toast method
            showToast("Unable to connect to Internet !");
            return false;
        }   
    }

//ping google and test internet connection
private boolean internetConnectionAvailable(int timeOut) {
        InetAddress inetAddress = null;
        try {
            Future<InetAddress> future = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(new Callable<InetAddress>() {
                @Override
                public InetAddress call() {
                    try {

                        return InetAddress.getByName("www.google.com");
                    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            });
            inetAddress = future.get(timeOut, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            future.cancel(true);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        }
        Log.e("Google",String.valueOf(inetAddress));
        return inetAddress!=null && !inetAddress.equals("");
    }
```

Comment: Have a look at this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238921/detect-whether-there-is-an-internet-connection-available-on-android and don't forget about permissions.

Comment: @Rohit you need to ping manually and see the response it it has 200 then you are good to go. Sample reference here
http://crunchify.com/how-to-get-ping-status-of-any-http-end-point-in-java/

Comment: Parviz Sattorov: Thanx. I have already declared the required permissions in Manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the internet is connected/not... If yes androidTask() is called.

```
 if (haveNetworkConnection()) {
                new androidTask().execute();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "No Network Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

**Called method of haveNetworkConnection():**

```
 public boolean haveNetworkConnection() {
        boolean haveConnectedWifi = false;
        boolean haveConnectedMobile = false;
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
        for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) {
            if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
                if (ni.isConnected())
                    haveConnectedWifi = true;
            if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
                if (ni.isConnected())
                    haveConnectedMobile = true;
        }
        return haveConnectedWifi || haveConnectedMobile;
    }
```

**Method contains HTTP request:**

```
 class androidTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        String BASE_URL = http://abc.def.com/";

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

            HttpURLConnection con = null;
            InputStream is = null;

            hashMapPost.put("report", "users");

            try {
                con = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL(BASE_URL)).openConnection();
                con.setDoInput(true);
                con.setDoOutput(true);
                con.setRequestMethod("POST");
                con.connect();
                OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
                writer.write(getPostDataString(hashMapPost));
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                os.close();
                buffer = new StringBuffer();
                int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
                if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    is = con.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                    String line;
                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                        buffer.append(line).append("\r\n");
                    is.close();
                }
                con.disconnect();
                return buffer.toString();
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (is != null) {
                        is.close();
                    }
                } catch (Throwable t) {
                }
                try {
                    if (con != null) {
                        con.disconnect();
                    }
                } catch (Throwable t) {
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

        }
    }
```

Comment: it checks but doesn't guarantee that data flow in on?